# Understanding module parameters in OCaml

Tags: functional-programming, ocaml

I'm trying to understand what's the point of this `connect` function:

```
let connect netif ethif arpv4 ipv4 icmpv4 udpv4 tcpv4 =
    let udpv4_listeners = Hashtbl.create 7 in
    let tcpv4_listeners = Hashtbl.create 7 in
    let t = { netif; ethif; arpv4; ipv4; icmpv4; tcpv4; udpv4;
              udpv4_listeners; tcpv4_listeners } in
    Log.info (fun f -> f "stack assembled: %a" pp t);
    Lwt.async (fun () -> listen t);
    Lwt.return t
```

My first assumption is: are the `netif ethif arpv4 ipv4 icmpv4 udpv4 tcpv4` parameters being taken to be by default the 'variables' of same name enclosed in the scope of the `connect` function definition?

Please see the entire context here: https://github.com/mirage/mirage-tcpip/blob/master/src/stack-direct/tcpip_stack_direct.ml#L122

If this is not the case, then does it mean that I need to **always** pass all these 7 parameters when I call `connect`? What's the point of passing them if they're already created [here](https://github.com/mirage/mirage-tcpip/blob/master/src/stack-direct/tcpip_stack_direct.ml#L46)?

Comment: "are the `netif ethif arpv4 ipv4 icmpv4 udpv4 tcpv4` parameters being taken to be by default the 'variables' of same name enclosed in the scope of the connect function definition? " No. `type t`  from line 46 is just a record type defined in the module, which happens to have the same element names as the argument names of the function `connect`. So `netif ethif arpv4 ipv4 icmpv4 udpv4 tcpv4` is just the arguments of the function.

Comment: I recommend learning OCaml by reading a book such as [Real World OCaml](https://dev.realworldocaml.org/) or [Functional Programming in OCaml](https://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs3110/2019sp/textbook/). It will be much faster than asking a million questions on Stack Overflow which most people won't want to answer because these things are already well-explained in proper learning resources.